How to use junit reporter from jasmine-reporters with jasmine command line utility?
With npm I have installed packages jasmine and jasmine-reporters. When I run npx jasmine, the tests run and I get the output in command line.
I want to get the report in JUnit format, for which there is a reporter in the jasmine-reporters.
The Jasmine cli tool accepts argument --reporter=, but I can't find a way to link those two tools together. What am I missing?
In comparison, the jest-junit module integrates easily with jest: install package, add one line to jest config file and  add --reporters=jest-junit to command line arguments.
